# File.listFiles() does not work on Linux

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, web

Ok. I have the following web app snippet (called in constructor - if that is important):

```
    private File[] logFiles;
    ...
    try {
        File directory = new File(auditDirectory);
        LOG.debug("Found directory: " + directory.getAbsolutePath());
        logFiles = directory.listFiles();           
        LOG.debug("Number of logFiles: " + logFiles.length);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOG.error("Exception: ", e);
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed to get list of audit files", e);
    }
```

In my windows environment (localhost) everything works like a charm. After deployment on linux (ubuntu) environment, seems that line

```
directory.listFiles();
```

returns null value. I have concluded that from the following linux deployment log:

```
c.a.s.a.a.AuditFileSource - Found directory: /home/myapp/myappfolder/logs
c.a.s.a.a.AuditFileSource - Exception: 
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.myapp.services.administration.audit.AuditFileSource.<init>(AuditFileSource.java:31) ~[com.myapp.services-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]
    at...
```

Log line AuditFileSource.java:31 is actually the line:

```
LOG.debug("Number of logFiles: " + logFiles.length);
```

and it is obvious that NullPointerException is raised as an attempt to access lenght on logFiles variable which is null.

My first try was to change permissions on relevant Linux folders but they already have read permissions. I'm completely puzzled. Any Idea?

Comment: It is directory. I can tell that after logging in with putty. It is directory and has log files inside.

Comment: That's not the same as seeing whether `directory.isDirectory()` returns true.

Comment: I already have execute permission... :/

Comment: Again, that doesn't answer the question: if you log `directory.isDirectory()`, what do you see?

Comment: Execute permissions IS NOT what you need to read the entries in a directory; what you need is _read_ permissions. You will need execute permissions if you `stat()` the file though.

Comment: Ok. I have put all permissions :) Nothing worked.

Comment: I just ran into the same null issue on ubuntu 16.04 with java 8 u101. Was frustrating!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's one of the numerous problems with `File`; its `.listFiles()` method is unreliable.

Try and use this instead:

```
final Path dir = Paths.get("path/to/directory");

final DirectoryStream<Path> dirStream = Files.newDirectoryStream(dir);

// use the stream
```

If the fs entry is not a directory, you'll at least get a `NotDirectoryException`; if you don't have enough permissions, you'll get an `AccessDeniedException`; etc etc.

Drop `File`. This is 2015, after all. And the new file API (aka JSR 203, aka NIO2) has been there since 2011!

---

Since Java 8 you can also use `Files.list()`; DO NOTE however that you SHOULD use it in a try-with-resources block like this:

```
try (
    final Stream<Path> stream = Files.list(thedir);
) {
    // use the stream
}
```

It is a little known fact that `Stream` (well, `BaseStream` in fact) implements `AutoCloseable`!

Comment: Wonder if they will eventually get listFiles() to work reliably. How would I use the stream to see if the directory is empty?

Comment: @simgineer you can check that its `.count()` is 0. As to `.listFiles()`, except for very critical bugs, chances are it won't be changed now.