# File.listFiles() failing in Linux

Tags: java, linux, file, nio

I am trying to list down the files from a directory and delete it. In Windows I do not face any issue. But when running on Linux it gave Failed to parse the file message. Any idea

fDelete is file path

```
    for (File file : fDelete.listFiles()) {
        deleteFile(file);
     }
```

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [File.listFiles() does not work on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28984430/file-listfiles-does-not-work-on-linux)

Comment: Do you really use `java.nio`? If yes, please point out which of your lines of code actually uses `java.nio`. At the moment, I can only see `File`, which I guess is from `java.io`.

Answer (score 0):

```java
final Path dir = Paths.get("path/to/directory");
final DirectoryStream<Path> dirStream = Files.newDirectoryStream(dir);
           
try (final Stream<Path> stream = Files.list(thedir)){
   …
}
```

Comment: The point here is not the streaming mechanism but the correct use of `java.nio` instead of `java.io`! Point that out in your answer and it is likely to get some upvotes... Oh, and please format your code example, it has no good readability.

Comment: Will correct it up @deHaar